# Mixing versions can lead runtime crashes

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Estou tendo um problema com `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0`. O AnddroidStudio diz que:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0 and com.android.support:design:26.1.0

Aí eu tentei explicitar o `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0`, mas não funcionou. Enfim, esse é meu Gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "******"
         minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 26
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
         multiDexEnabled true
     }

     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
     implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
     annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
     compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
     compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
     compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

     //Firebase
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'

     //Google services
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'


     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Também não sei como nem se devo mudar o `targetSdkVersion` ou `compileSdkVersion` para o 27, aberto para isso também =)

Ah, e quando eu tento rodar o projeto eu tenho o seguinte `erro::app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug`. Espero q isso possa ajudar

Comment: Resolvi alterando todos os compiles para implementation e para "27.0.1", a compileSdkVersion e 
 targetSdkVersion para 27 e buildToolsVersion para 27.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona esse código no final do build.gradle (Module:app).

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '27.1.1'
        }
    }
}
```

}

E troca todos os `compile` por `implementation`.